# Can be selected only once with Picker in Form

Tags: swiftui

I am using Xcode 11.3 with SwiftUI.

I have a picker on the form, but I can only select it once.

How do I choice again?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedNumber = 1

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Picker(selection: $selectedNumber, label: Text("Select a number.")) {
                    ForEach(1 ..< 10) {
                        Text("\($0)")
                    }
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("Test form")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it on a real iOS13.3 machine and it worked.
Maybe a simulator problem.

Comment: I tried with the latest xcode（11.3.1）, but it has not been fixed yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem with the simulator included with Xcode13.
The simulator attached to Xcode14 confirmed that the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

With Xcode 11.2 just works. Try the following variants:

1) Use .tag

```
Text("\($0)").tag($0)
```

2) Use .id for selection

```
Text("\($0)").id($0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice.Certainly it works fine in 11.2.
But in 11.3, both cases work only once.